# How to store properties on the GAE Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new in the app engine platform and I would like to know how to store a contact, email address, and a geographical position in an entity using GAE Java. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You store the fields in an entity. Each entity has a key to index it. Then you persist it to the datastore. Read the documents at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata